# Testcafe: foreach counter

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using foreach to read data from js file.  Is there a way to find out the current index in loop?

Example: I have 10 rows of data.  I would like to print the index (1,2..10) everytime the test block is run.  In a simple for loop, I would use the counter variable (say, i).

```
urlMain.forEach(data => {
    test("Lens", async t => {
        await t.navigateTo(data.new);
        await t.takeScreenshot()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let i = 0;
urlMain.forEach(data => {
    console.log(++i);
    test("Lens", async t => {
        await t.navigateTo(data.new);
        await t.takeScreenshot()
    })
})
```

Comment: thank you very much.  i feel really bad for not thinking out-of-the-box :(

Comment: Hi Alex, When i tried this, it actually prints 1 to 9 right away (even before going into the test block).  If i try to print it inside test block, it always prints 10.  I am using testcafe 1.8.4.  Could you help please?

Comment: Strangely, it works only in this part - test("Lens_" + i, async t.  The test name gets properly incremented everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Alex's answer, we can get it work with 2 counters in Testcafe 1.8.4.

```
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
const testName = "Lens"
urlMain.forEach(data => {
    i = i + 1;
    test(testName + "_" + i, async t => {
        j = j + 1;
        const sPath = testName + "_" + j + "/actual.png";
        await t.navigateTo(data.new);
        await t.maximizeWindow()
        await t.wait(5000)
        console.log(sPath);
        await t.takeScreenshot({
            path: sPath,
            fullPage: true
        });
    })
})
```